# How to install google-ads (grpcio) in AWS ec2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-ads-api, grpcio

I want to use `google-ads` in AWS EC2.

I try to install it with, `pip install google-ads` but this throws an error.

Error:

```
ssm-user@ip-172-31-47-200:/var/snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552$ pip install pip install google-ads
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/ca/f0d790b6e18b3a6f3bd5e80c2ee4edbb5807286c21cdd0862ca933f751dd/pip-21.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.6MB 871kB/s
Collecting install
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/a5/fd2eb807a9a593869ee8b7a6bcb4ad84a6eb31cef5c24d1bfbf7c938c13f/install-1.3.4-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting google-ads
Collecting grpcio<2.0.0,>=1.33.2 (from google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cd/80/4b65b06e35599af065076891248b88d16c87cee1121b8886316ad4343f50/grpcio-1.38.1.tar.gz
Collecting PyYAML<6.0,>=5.1 (from google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7a/5b/bc0b5ab38247bba158504a410112b6c03f153c652734ece1849749e5f518/PyYAML-5.4.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting google-auth-oauthlib<1.0.0,>=0.3.0 (from google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9d/d3/7541e89f1fc456eef157224f597a8bba22589db6369a03eaba68c11f07a0/google_auth_oauthlib-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting google-api-core<2.0.0,>=1.21.0 (from google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f6/72/6dc3c3c4576fedc409fd825bf71e22d0f448bd68143c79cdbd6216744282/google_api_core-1.30.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting dataclasses<1.0.0,>=0.6; python_version < "3.7" (from google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/ca/75fac5856ab5cfa51bbbcefa250182e50441074fdc3f803f6e76451fab43/dataclasses-0.8-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting nox==2020.12.31 (from google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d3/a6/6a6a1cca717bf241323ec1bfa5b679b643437fee3c26af2387d3766a8986/nox-2020.12.31-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting proto-plus<2.0.0,>=1.18.0 (from google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/72/6f3f4cdc5bb0294f8d7f3f8aacb617b4c3cb17554ed78f7e28009162c795/proto_plus-1.19.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools>=40.3.0 (from google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/e1/902fbc2f61ad6243cd3d57ffa195a9eb123021ec912ec5d811acf54a39f8/setuptools-57.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting googleapis-common-protos<2.0.0,>=1.5.8 (from google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/55/08/796a6bc0b550e2b7116041c953d3d5100016abea106131d71e5651826e7b/googleapis_common_protos-1.53.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pep562<2.0,>=1.0 (from google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8f/b9/8a74b93c643b54cc7579087ff6a56aa1a9c52329be6846abfbaee4a7828b/pep562-1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.5.2 (from grpcio<2.0.0,>=1.33.2->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d9/5a/e7c31adbe875f2abbb91bd84cf2dc52d792b5a01506781dbcf25c91daf11/six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting google-auth>=1.0.0 (from google-auth-oauthlib<1.0.0,>=0.3.0->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6e/1d/e4718af587967b8fb6ac7e0e257809934005a3f8fde8f31a304c7e682874/google_auth-1.32.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 (from google-auth-oauthlib<1.0.0,>=0.3.0->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/12/b92740d845ab62ea4edf04d2f4164d82532b5a0b03836d4d4e71c6f3d379/requests_oauthlib-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting protobuf>=3.12.0 (from google-api-core<2.0.0,>=1.21.0->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/53/4e/e2db88d0bb0bda6a879eea62fddbaf813719ce3770d458bc5580512d9c95/protobuf-3.17.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0 (from google-api-core<2.0.0,>=1.21.0->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/29/c1/24814557f1d22c56d50280771a17307e6bf87b70727d975fd6b2ce6b014a/requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting packaging>=14.3 (from google-api-core<2.0.0,>=1.21.0->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/77/e2362b676dc5008d81be423070dd9577fa03be5da2ba1105811900fda546/packaging-21.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz (from google-api-core<2.0.0,>=1.21.0->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/70/94/784178ca5dd892a98f113cdd923372024dc04b8d40abe77ca76b5fb90ca6/pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting virtualenv>=14.0.0 (from nox==2020.12.31->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/08/f819421002e85a71d58368f7bffbe0b1921325e0e8ca7857cb5fb0e1f7c1/virtualenv-20.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting argcomplete<2.0,>=1.9.4 (from nox==2020.12.31->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/9e/9dc74d330c07866d72f62d553fe8bdbe32786ff247a14e68b5659963e6bd/argcomplete-1.12.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting py<2.0.0,>=1.4.0 (from nox==2020.12.31->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/32/6fe01cfc3d1a27c92fdbcdfc3f67856da8cbadf0dd9f2e18055202b2dc62/py-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting colorlog<5.0.0,>=2.6.1 (from nox==2020.12.31->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/62/61449c6bb74c2a3953c415b2cdb488e4f0518ac67b35e2b03a6d543035ca/colorlog-4.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8" (from nox==2020.12.31->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3f/e1/e5bba549a033adf77448699a34ecafc7a32adaeeb4369396b35f56d5cc3e/importlib_metadata-4.6.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 (from google-auth>=1.0.0->google-auth-oauthlib<1.0.0,>=0.3.0->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bf/28/c4f5796c67ad06bb91d98d543a5e01805c1ff065e08871f78e52d2a331ad/cachetools-4.2.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 (from google-auth>=1.0.0->google-auth-oauthlib<1.0.0,>=0.3.0->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/95/de/214830a981892a3e286c3794f41ae67a4495df1108c3da8a9f62159b9a9d/pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting rsa<5,>=3.1.4; python_version >= "3.6" (from google-auth>=1.0.0->google-auth-oauthlib<1.0.0,>=0.3.0->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/93/0c0f002031f18b53af7a6166103c02b9c0667be528944137cc954ec921b3/rsa-4.7.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting oauthlib>=3.0.0 (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<1.0.0,>=0.3.0->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/5d/9dd1c29e5a786525f6342f6c1d812ed2e37edc653ad297048c1668988053/oauthlib-3.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 (from requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0->google-api-core<2.0.0,>=1.21.0->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/64/43575537846896abac0b15c3e5ac678d787a4021e906703f1766bfb8ea11/urllib3-1.26.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<5,>=3.0.2 (from requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0->google-api-core<2.0.0,>=1.21.0->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/c7/fa589626997dd07bd87d9269342ccb74b1720384a4d739a1872bd84fbe68/chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5 (from requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0->google-api-core<2.0.0,>=1.21.0->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/38/928ddce2273eaa564f6f50de919327bf3a00f091b5baba8dfa9460f3a8a8/idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0->google-api-core<2.0.0,>=1.21.0->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/1b/0a0dece0e8aa492a6ec9e4ad2fe366b511558cdc73fd3abc82ba7348e875/certifi-2021.5.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyparsing>=2.0.2 (from packaging>=14.3->google-api-core<2.0.0,>=1.21.0->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/bb/488841f56197b13700afd5658fc279a2025a39e22449b7cf29864669b15d/pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting filelock<4,>=3.0.0 (from virtualenv>=14.0.0->nox==2020.12.31->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/83/71a2ee6158bb9f39a90c0dea1637f81d5eef866e188e1971a1b1ab01a35a/filelock-3.0.12-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting distlib<1,>=0.3.1 (from virtualenv>=14.0.0->nox==2020.12.31->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/26/f6a23dd3e578132cf924e0dd5d4e055af0cd4ab43e2a9f10b7568bfb39d9/distlib-0.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting importlib-resources>=1.0; python_version < "3.7" (from virtualenv>=14.0.0->nox==2020.12.31->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/8d/cb49c07dd01e797e76e86f33c3472ebd861216b57296095f5c17be9b79e8/importlib_resources-5.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 (from virtualenv>=14.0.0->nox==2020.12.31->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/00/2344469e2084fb287c2e0b57b72910309874c3245463acd6cf5e3db69324/appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.6.4; python_version < "3.8" (from importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"->nox==2020.12.31->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/35/6c4fff5ab443b57116cb1aad46421fb719bed2825664e8fe77d66d99bcbc/typing_extensions-3.10.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting zipp>=0.5 (from importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"->nox==2020.12.31->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/92/d9/89f433969fb8dc5b9cbdd4b4deb587720ec1aeb59a020cf15002b9593eef/zipp-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth>=1.0.0->google-auth-oauthlib<1.0.0,>=0.3.0->google-ads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/1e/a94a8d635fa3ce4cfc7f506003548d0a2447ae76fd5ca53932970fe3053f/pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: grpcio
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for grpcio ... /
```

***After this, a wired thing happen my ssh stop responding until I restart the AWS EC2***

---

**My Environment**

- Python version = 3.6.9
- pip verions = 9.0.1
- Ubuntu version = 8.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

---

**Note:**  I also have REST API use `Nginx` reverse proxy a Node server via `pm2`

Comment: Take a look at the kernel logs

Comment: You can run the `dmesg` command. Not a lot of info here but I suspect out of memory. How large is the instance?

Comment: @jordanm i was using `t2.micro`, (i also tried `t2.small`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following @jordanm's path I found that pip install is building some wheels (which is a heavy task and need more memory and resources)

---

### Solution

1. Change your instance type to higher tier's (temporary) *[Select the instance > right click > change instance type > choose whatever you want, I go with **t3.xlarge**]*
2. SSH into your machine
3. Run the pip install commend, (If it crashes or frizzy again just repeat step 1 with higher tier instance type)
4. When the commend is successfully executed change back to your instance type. (if you want t to)

Answer (score -1):

It's building the wheels. First time it does that will take ages, especially on a small instance.